# identify redirection outside the domain

Tags: python, http, python-requests

How can I check if a link will direct to a link outside the domain?

I'm trying the code below without success. Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?

```py
import requests

def check_redirect(url):
    try:
        response = requests.head(url, allow_redirects=True)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            print(response.status_code)
            return url, "Not"
        elif response.status_code == 301 or response.status_code == 302:
            redirected_url = response.headers['Location']
            return url, f"YES to: {redirected_url}"
        else:
            return url, f"status_code {response.status_code}"
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        return url, f"Error: {str(e)}"

url = "https://www.gazetadopovo.com.br/conteudo-publicitario/some-control-summit/daos-conheca-organizacao-baseada-em-redes-blockchain/"
print(check_redirect(url))
```

Comment: What does this do when you get a redirect?  By saying `allow_redirects=True`, you are allowing `requests` to handle the redirects automatically.  Perhaps you should set that `False`, so YOU get to handle the redirects.

Comment: @TimRoberts I tried, but I can't find the redirect

Comment: If you turn `allow_redrect` off, then you should get some kind of 300 status that has a Location, unless they're doing it in Javascript.

Comment: @TimRoberts the example above always enters "if 200"

Comment: Did you turn off `allow_redirect`?  Have you done debugging to print the response text you get back?